# Setting Decimals by Attribute

Tags: product-attribute

I have multiple numeric attributes.  What I need to be able to do is show each attribute with the appropriate number of digitals after dot.

Some are ######0, some are #####0.00, #####0.000, #####0.0000, etc.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what kind of attributes you means.

I suggest you have EAV attributes with `backend_type=price`.
As I know Magento doesn't have such possibility out of the box.

**By default** all your prices will be in format ###.0000 because values for this attribute is being stored in *_entity_decimal table with data type DECIMAL(12,4) and Magento doesn't change it.

You must customize it yourself.

As a variant, you can do it in backend model(see table `eav_attributes`, field `backend_model`) for your attributes.
I.e

```
<?php

class DigitsAfterDot extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\AbstractBackend
{
    public function afterLoad($object)
    {
        $value = $object->getData($this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode());
        //convert value to have desirable number of digits
        $object->setData($this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode(), $value);
        return parent::afterLoad($object);
    }
}
```